# windows phone 8 background app run under lock screen button event

Tags: windows-phone-8

I made an application for Windows Phone 8 which features press three time lock button. My problem is, that as soon as the phone locks the screen, I want my application to run in background. I can't figure out a 'clean' way to do this.Can we run background app when lock screen enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will allow your app to continue to run when the lock screen is activated:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks....I tried it earlier. But it works fine when application is running. but I require when application is in background then I press 3 times lock screen button then some functionality of my app get execute. Hope u understand my point.

Comment: @rozy this is not possible. The reason is that there is no event handler that allows you to execute code frome your app when the lock screen button is pressed.